# making an angular1 form dirty via js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am sending form data to a login/password and then wanting to click the submit button, the problem is with the form validation requiring the form to be dirty. And I am directly assigning the values which means the form is not considered dirty and modified. I have tried focus but that doesn't seem to work either. The submit button won't appear because it isn't validated.

```
document.getElementById("email").focus(); 
document.getElementById("password").focus();
var e = document.getElementById("email"); 
e.value = 'currentEmployee@email.com';
var p = document.getElementById("password");
p.value = 'currentEmployee.password';
var osbut = document.getElementById("loginForm"); osbut.submit();
```

I am injected a script via a chrome extension, running it as a content.js script. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See examples that dispatch `change` event, or alternatively change the elements via document.execCommand 'insertText'

Comment: Please post an answer so I can give you credit. It worked perfectly. Thankyou. I used document.execCommand 'insertText'

Comment: Possible duplicate of following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651931/how-to-setdirty-to-a-single-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See examples that dispatch change event, or alternatively change the elements via document.execCommand 'insertText' – wOxxOm

This worked perfectly. I just wanted to close out the question. -Hunter

Answer (score 0):

Just set In Controller Form as valid. For example:

```
$scope.formName.$valid=true;
```